# can I pass props with additional distructured value?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-state

I am trying to get pass values from redux, and can I pass values as props and another destructured value?

my code is like this:

```
function MyFunction(props, {cityData}) {
  console.log(props);

  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchCity();
  }, []);

  return props.cityData.loading ? (
    <Typography>Loading</Typography>
  ) : props.cityData.error ? (
    <Typography>{props.cityData.message}</Typography>
  ) : (
    <div></div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You can destructure your props like in the example below based on your code

```
function MyFunction(props) {
  console.log(props);
  const {cityData} = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchCity();
  }, []);

  return cityData.loading ? (
    <Typography>Loading</Typography>
  ) : cityData.error ? (
    <Typography>{cityData.message}</Typography>
  ) : (
    <div></div>
  );
}
```